# When trying to utilize make patch, I get “fatal: ambiguous argument 'origin/master': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.”

Tags: git, ubuntu, makefile

I've been scratching my head for this problem for a few good hours. For clarification, I am operating on a Ubuntu 20.04 (VM if it matters) and I encountered an error when trying to utilize the Makefile in the following way:

[Screenshot of Error Message on Ubuntu Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVCy1.png)

The error reads: `fatal: ambiguous argument 'origin/master': unknown revision or path not in the working tree. make: *** [Makefile:64: patch] Error 128`

As you can see, I have initialized a git repository before utilizing the make patch. I am lost; if there is anything else I can provide to clarify my issue even further or things that I can try, please let me know. To provide more clarification, I'm essentially trying to patch up my solution code with this Makefile. I had already finished writing the solution code (which works) and I am trying to patch it up to send.

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have an `origin/master`.

> As you can see, I have initialized a git repository before utilizing the make patch ...

That's not how `make patch` was intended to be used, though: the theory here was that you would clone some *existing* Git repository (to make your new local Git repository).  You would then do work in the working tree *of* your Git repository, maybe make new commits—the details depend on what whoever wrote this particular `Makefile` was thinking—and then eventually run `make patch`.  This would use your local Git's `origin/master` *remote-tracking name*, which is your local Git's memory of some other Git's *branch* `master`.

You didn't follow this particular process.  Perhaps you started from scratch, with an empty Git repository.  You then put some files into it, including this `Makefile`.  Or, perhaps you cloned a repository whose main branch was not `master`, but rather `main`, and so you have an `origin/main` and a `main`.

Whatever the actual case is, the process you followed is not quite the one envisioned by whoever wrote this particular `Makefile` entry.  Their `make patch` assumed you would have an `origin/master`.  You don't.

What's not clear is whether you *should*.  Perhaps their thinking was flawed: perhaps you do have an `origin/main`, and they should have assumed that you would have an `origin/main`.  Or, perhaps you don't have a *remote* named `origin` at all.

Whatever the situation is, you cannot use this particular Makefile target the way you are trying to use it, right now: something has to change, whether that's the process you used to get to this point, or the Makefile target, or both.